# Clickable link in the TreeDataProvider

Tags: node.js, vscode-extensions

I have created a plugin whose response are displayed as rows under TreeDataProvider. In that, among other details, i have one child as "Name" and another "url". Is it possible to have "Name" as a link on which when I click, in background it opens the url in a browser?

[image: Updated the screenshot after the fix.]
Updated the image after the fix. Now it's opening the link outside in a browser. Can i make only label clickable? Also, can I underline the label to show that its a link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.
You can make a tree item clickable by providing it with `vscode.open` command:

```
let treeItem: vscode.TreeItem = new vscode.TreeItem(name);
treeItem.command = {
    command: 'vscode.open',
    arguments: [vscode.Uri.parse(url)]
} as vscode.Command;
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked like a charm. I have another related query. For every tree-item, i have children. The above code is making the complete tree-item clickable. Is it possible to only make the label clickable? Also, can i underline the label? <Updating my original post with screenshot of the output>

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out:

```
            element.children[0].command = {
                command: 'vscode.open',
                arguments: [vscode.Uri.parse('https://www.google.com')]
            } as vscode.Command;
```